# Notation for Permuting Sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

If I have some arbitrary sets $A_i : i \in I$ and I want to permute their intersections pairwise, how would I write such a permutation? Would I use some permutation tensor? Essentially I want to permute $A_i \cap A_k \, \, \forall i,k \in I$. How would I notate this formally?

Comment: What, exactly, do you mean here by *permute*? Do you simply mean that you want to be able to refer to the collection of all such intersections, or do you want to do something more complicated?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott For this case I simply want to cover all pairwise intersections over the index set $I$

Comment: Do you want just the intersections with $i\ne k$, or do you also want to include the sets $A_i$ themselves?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Only the $i \neq k$ cases for this purpose

Comment: Okay; I’ll have an answer in a moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want $$\left\{A_i\cap A_k:\{i,k\}\in[I]^2\right\}\;.$$ The notation $[X]^\kappa$, where $X$ is any set and $\kappa$ is any cardinal number, is defined to be $$[X]^\kappa=\{S\subseteq X:|S|=\kappa\}\;,$$ the family of subsets of $X$ of cardinality $\kappa$. This is a standard notation, but it’s not universally familiar, so you’d probably want to define it first.

Comment: Much appreciated. So if I wanted to *permute* $\lambda$ sets, it would simply be $$\bigcap_{a_i \in I} A_{a_i} : \{a_1, \ldots a_\lambda\} \in [I]^{\lambda}$$?

Comment: @Anthony: If you mean that you want to look at $\lambda$-fold intersections, I’d write a typical one as $\bigcap_{i\in J}A_i$, where $J\in[I]^\lambda$. The set of all such intersections would be $$\left\{\bigcap_{i\in J}A_i:J\in[I]^\lambda\right\}\;.$$

Comment: @Anthony: You’re welcome.

Comment: $[X]^\kappa$ is also written as $\binom{X}{\kappa}$.